# HttpClient throws error for the following code

Tags: android

The inputstream shows  output in logcat as "org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@527021ec" and output throws error. It is bez the login fails or I have made any mistake in code. Plz help...Attached the logcat image below.

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(UrlLink);
    try {
        // Add user name and password

        String username = "xaeroprasad";
        String password = "ramesh88";
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        Log.v("SENCIDE", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        InputStream is=response.getEntity().getContent();
        Log.v("ddd",is.toString());
        String line = "";
         StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
         BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

         try {
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            total.append(line); 
          }
          Log.v("dfd",line);
         } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Logcat output:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKZgE.png

Answer (score 1):

You're running a loop until `line` is null:

```
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
    total.append(line); 
}
```

And when it's over (`line == null`) you print the `line`:

```
Log.v("dfd",line);
```

That throws an error because Log's second parameter can't be null.

You probably wanted to Log `total` after the loop:

```
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
    total.append(line); 
}
Log.v("dfd", total);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
    total.append(line); 
  }
  Log.v("dfd",total); //<-- Edit this, its a Typo
 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```